# Default http port for lcoin?

Tags: litecoin, bcoin

What is the default http port that lcoin listens on? bcoin listens on port 18332 for http by default, however lcoin documentation links only point to bcoin doc links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lcoin listens on port 19336 by default, however you can set another port by using the `--http-port=<your port>` flag when starting the node